# 2D Chladni patterns realistic animation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, wave-propagation

My wish is to create a (realistic) animation of the patterns appearing during the Chladni experiment.
I tried something, but it is not continuous because it is based on the eigenmodes, so the simulation aspect I want to obtain is not here. In order to illustrate my demand, see this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qqeb.jpg

Many thanks in advance for your answers. I love this website :)

My code below (Sorry, I don't know how to put the animation window inside this post):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; ClearAll[vals, funs, x, y];

 \[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]; 

 {vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 40]; 

 Animate[ContourPlot[funs[[i]] == 0, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega],
   PlotPoints -> 25, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, 1, Length[vals], 1}]
```

**Remarks :**

1. I choosed to plot the nodals lines : ContourPlot[funs[[i]] **== 0**, but is also possible to do it with "normal" ContourPlot or even with DensityPlot.
2. The used equation is based on the elastic membrane theory (one Laplacian with clamped edges), not on the free edges plate theory. This last one is too much tricky for me with the double-laplacian, but according to me, it should be the "graal".
3. It is also possible to do it in 3D with this code :

```
Animate[Plot3D[funs[[i]], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, 1, Length[vals], 1}]
```

Done on Mathematica v12.2

---

I tried this, but it is not working :

```
Do[Animate[
  Plot3D[Sin[t] funs[[normalmode]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> 0.2 {-1, 1}, Mesh -> True], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], { 
  normalmode, 40}]
```

---

Thank you, Daniel. Your idea is very interesting. In fact, I wish to chain all modes smoothly from the first one to the last one (the last computed one) as it is depicted in the animated gif here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qqeb.jpg

So, if it is possible to vary normalmode from 1 to N (40 for example) with the same idea, it should be interesting.

Answer (score 8):

We can use elastic plate equation to generate eigenfunctions as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {20, 20}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> .1, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
Y = 200*10^9;(*steel Y=200 GPa*)nu = 25/100; rho = 7700; h = .001; d =
  10^4 Sqrt[
   Y h^2/(12 rho (1 - nu^2))]; Ld2 = {Laplacian[-d u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
   v[x, y], -d Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}]};

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{Ld2, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, {u, v},
     Element[{x, y}, mesh], 35] // Quiet;

Table[DensityPlot[Re[funs[[i, 1]][x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]]/(2 Pi), 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Frame -> False], {i, 2, Length[vals]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

To animate patterns we use linear combination of eigenfunctions with "time" dependence in a form

```
frames = Table[
   Table[DensityPlot[
     Abs[Exp[-t] funs[[i, 1]][x, y] + (1 - Exp[-t]) funs[[i + 1, 1]][
         x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
     Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Small, 
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x}, 
       Blend[{White, Darker@Green, White}, 2 ArcTan[350 x]/Pi + .5]], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {t, 0, 2, .5}], {i, 10, 34}];

Export["D:\\Animation\\chl11.gif", frames // Flatten, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you again, Alex.
Your solution is elegant.

Comment: I read some papers about vibration plates theory and also elastic membrane theory and I don't understand the main equation :

Ld2 = {Laplacian[-d u[x, y], {x, y}] + v[x, y], -d Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}]};

Why are there 2 Laplacians within the equation? Could you explain me?

When there are 2 Laplacians, it concerns the bi-harmonoc equation. here, it is the case, isn't it?

Comment: @Pascal77 Yes, this is the case. If we have bi-hormonic equation $\nabla^2 (\nabla ^2 u)=0$, then we put $v=\nabla ^2 u$ and therefore $\nabla ^2 v=0$. In a case of dynamic equation there is also $u_{tt}$, but since we a looking for the eigenfunctions we can use the system as I proposed above.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily draw an animation for the normal mode as you know that the normal modes change sinusoidally with time. Here is an example where I set the frequency arbitrarily to one. If needed you may also take this into account:

```
normalmode = 5;
Animate[
  Plot3D[Sin[t]  funs[[normalmode]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> 0.2 {-1, 1}, Mesh -> True]
 , {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]